# I have tried data binding in android studio 2.3,but it giving error

Tags: android, android-studio

**I have tried a simple example of data binding, but its giving error.**

While i try to run this code it's giving **"Error:(122, 95) error: cannot find symbol variable com"**

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
    User user=new User("Android","Dev");
    activityMainBinding.setUser(user);    }
```

}

**User.class**

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String lastName;
public User(String name, String lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="root.com.myapplicationbinding.MainActivity">
    <data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="root.com.myapplicationbinding.User" />
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstnameLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{user.name}" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstnameTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{user.lastName}"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstnameLabel"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Are you sure about `root.com.myapplicationbinding.User`? Is this the correct path?

Comment: try to replace ActivityMainBinding  with ViewDataBinding and comment further code in MainActivity.java. Then try to build it. Let us know it is working fine or not?